# Namespacing all classes within a Ruby Gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Ok so I'm assuming this is either super trivial or not possible, but either way I'm struggling to find an answer on the issue.

I'm making a gem in ruby right now that has many classes in many different files, all imported in the main gem file like so:

```
# lib/main_gem_file.rb

module MainGemFile 
  Dir[File.join(__dir__, 'main_gem_file', '*.rb')].each do |file|
    require file 
  end
end
```

This works fine and all of my files are loaded. The problem is, none of them are loaded under the MainGemFile namespace. Currently, none of the class files in the main_gem_file use the namespace in their definition, so they look like the following:

```
# lib/main_gem_file/class_one.rb

class ClassOne
end
```

Ideally I would find a way to do the following:

1. Load all classes from lib files into the specific module (MainGemFile) without needing to namespace each individual class (obviously I could do MainGemFile::ClassA at the top of each class, but this feels like a lot of grunt work since I have a lot of classes, and I'm assuming their should be some easy way to do this automatically in the main_gem_file.rb file.

Additionally, I would love to structure everything in a way that any ruby project that requires this gem must use MainGemFile::ClassA syntax to access a Class, while allowing the actually internal classes of the the gem to access their sibling classes with just the ClassA call since they are defined in the same module. Again, feels like grunt work to have to go through and manually add MainGemFile:: before every class call, but will do it if their is no other solution.

Comment: @jvillian yeah I've looked in to that but from what I understand engines are only for rails, and I want my gem to work on both rails and plain ruby projects

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You need to write e.g. `module MainGemFile; class ClassOne`, or `class MainGemFile::ClassOne` in each file. Explicitly writing the `module` is generally the preferred approach.

Comment: When you `require` a file, I don't think there's any way to "require it within a context" (i.e. within a module). If that were possible, it would lead to all sorts of weird behaviour... For example, even in your simple example, the definition of `ClassOne` would change depending on which file gets loaded!!

Comment: Can you find any example of another gem that loads its classes in the way you describe?